# Slow filling of matrix with 2D-key:value data

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a data set with over 11 million records of 3 variables.  I have created a map like this:

```
map <- matrix(, nrow = 115, ncol = 42)
map[(2:nrow(map)),1]<-sapply(1:(nrow(map)-1), function(x) 420+5*(x-1))
map[1,(2:ncol(map))] <- sapply(1:(ncol(map)-1), function(x) -10+.5*(x-1))
```

I want to look through each of the entries and if two conditions are met, store the value of the first column in a vector.  Then at the end, take the average of that vector and store it in the map.

```
for ( i in 2:42){
  for (j in 2:2){
    values <- c()
    sapply(1:nrow(data),function(k){
        if (data[k,2] == map[j,1] & data[k,3] == map[1,i]){
           values<-c(values,data[k,1])
        }
     })
     if(length(values) != 0){
       map[j,i] = mean(values)
     }
 }
}
```

The first problem is that it takes forever.  The second issu is the map isn't updating, but I believe that can be fixed once when the first problem is addressed.  I have no experience in parallel processing, but do have some with the apply family.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What language are you using? Is that R? In that case you should edit your post and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Removed the bigdata and parallelization tags. They don't really apply to this medium-sized task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you will later want to move the coordinates of this "map"-object to the rownames and colnames locations but something like this should be a whole lot faster:

This is a "data" example:

```
data <- cbind( value=sample(36),  expand.grid(x=1:6, y=1:6))

dat2 <- as.data.frame( as.table (  tapply(data[,1], list( x=data[,2], y=data[,3] ), 
                                     FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE) ) )
map[ cbind( 1+as.numeric(dat2[,1]), 1+as.numeric(d

at2[,2])) ]  <- dat2[,3]
> map[1:10,1:10]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   NA  -10 -9.5   -9 -8.5   -8 -7.5   -7 -6.5    -6
 [2,]  420   27 10.0   22 28.0   21 25.0   NA   NA    NA
 [3,]  425    7 11.0    1 20.0    4  6.0   NA   NA    NA
 [4,]  430   16  9.0   24 23.0   18 30.0   NA   NA    NA
 [5,]  435   26  2.0   35 12.0   34 32.0   NA   NA    NA
 [6,]  440    3 14.0   19  5.0   15  8.0   NA   NA    NA
 [7,]  445   33 17.0   31 29.0   36 13.0   NA   NA    NA
 [8,]  450   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [9,]  455   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[10,]  460   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

You need to post code to make a proper testcase for the `data`-object.